# Image or Pdf File download from Gcloud Storage is corrupted

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, mandrill, gcloud-java

I am using file downloaded from Gcloud storage as attachment to Mandrill API for sending as an attachment in email. The problem is it's only working for Text file, **but for Image or Pdf, the attachment is corrupted.**
Following Code is for downloading the file and converting it to Base64 encoded String.

```
Storage.Objects.Get getObject = getService().objects().get(bucket, object);

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // If you're not in AppEngine, download the whole thing in one request, if possible.
    getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(true);
    getObject.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);
    //log.info("Output: {}", out.toString("UTF-8"));
    return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(out.toString("UTF-8")
        .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

I am setting this String in Content of MessageContent of Mandrill API.

Comment: Since MessageContent.Content expects a String, not a byte array, I assume you are passing base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(out.toString("UTF-8")) as MessageContent but only using getBytes() here to test the corruption?

Comment: Yes that is the reason why i am using base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString but i have also tried Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(out.toByteArray()) which yields the same result. Only text files are coming properly rest are corrupted.

Comment: I reckon the problem is with downloading complete data at once. Because with more testing i see that big text files are also not fetching all data as some parts are corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. I only needed to store the OutputStream in a temp File before using it as attachment in email. Posting the code below for reference.

```
Storage.Objects.Get getObject = storage.objects().get("bucket", "object");

OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/object");
// If you're not in AppEngine, download the whole thing in one request, if possible.
getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(true);
getObject.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);
```